# Is it possible to track Mobile/Desktop model in AngularJS, JavaScript and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to track User's mobile/desktop device, browser platform, OS Name/Version in either of JavaScript, JQuery and AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular as your frontend then [ngx-device-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector)

will help you to get the help to identify a browser, OS, and other useful information regarding the device using the app. The processing is based on user-agent.